# DB2 LIKE matching Pattern

Tags: sql, regex, db2, sql-like, db2-400

My question is simple.

In a DB2 Database, I have my table

```
Table (Id integer, name varchar)
```

I want to select entries which names like 'ac1%' or 'ac2%' or 'ac3%', so which names match regex

```
'^ac[123]*'
```

Is there any method to have this select query without write :

```
WHERE name LIKE 'ac1%' OR name LIKE 'ac2%' OR name LIKE 'ac2%'
```

Answer (score 6):

Probably the most efficient method is:

```
where name >= 'ac1' and
      name < 'ac4'
```

You can also use [regular expressions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzregexp_like.htm):

```
where regexp_like(name, '^ac[1-3]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Db2-server platform (Z/OS, i-Series, Linux/Unix/Windows) and Db2-version, you can use **REGEXP_LIKE** function. This allows regular expressions in SQL.

See documentation and examples [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061494.html).

Comment: Always write your Db2-platform and Db2-version when asking for help. Don't write "there was an error", instead write *exactly* what the error was.

Comment: Error Message :  QQQSVREG of type *SVRPGM not found in QSYS (State S0002, Native Code: FFFFFF34)

Comment: That message comes from i-Series Db2 (formerly OS/400).  *Current* versions of Db2 for i  do support regular expressions. You may be using an old downlevel version that lacks this function.  You should tag your question with the db2400 tag so people can see you are using i-Series.  Also specify your Db2-version.

Comment: DSPPTF will show the OS version.  In some shops, programmers do not have access to that command.  You could look at the output of any compiler like CRTCLPGM, or ask the system administrator the OS version.

Answer (score 0):

i think below will work  cause `REGEXP_LIKE(col,'[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}')` will always return true if `col` contain any of 0 to 9 value

```
  SELECT * FROM table1 
   WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(name,'[1-3]')
```